# Bootstrap v2.3.2 grid não funciona em IE9

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma grid em Bootstrap v2.3.2, que estou a tentar corrigir para correr em IE9. Na pagina oficial as grids mostram corretamente em IE9, por isso esperava o mesmo resultado.

Vi algumas respostas com Respond.js e outras técnicas para IE8, mas penso que se aplica apenas a BS3.

Julgo que o código que rodeia a grid afeta a sua visualização. Como melhorar este HTML e CSS?

Código:
http://jsfiddle.net/fpmsusm5/

Resultado expectável:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Aqui funciona bem no IE9.

Comment: Usar uma versão tão depreciada é complicado - Creio que seja melhor você atualizar pro 3.x e utilizar o http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: @Jorge tem razao, era o html que envolvia o accordion, obrigao pela ajuda

Comment: @dHeku Sim utilizar BS3 seria melhor, mas de momento como é um projeto grande estamos ainda limitados a utilizar BS2 até mudarmos em todo o projeto ou gradualmente. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @dotmindlabs ficou resolvido? Coloque a solução como resposta se achar que essa solução ajudará alguém no futuro.